# Creating instance of class on every function call vs. passing instance of class as a parameter

Tags: c#, .net

As title of question says, I was wondering which is correct approach. To clear my question I would like to give an example.

Suppose in main method of my program I give series of calls to method/methods which all make use of a instance of a class. So-

1. Should I create an instance of this class in the method body on every call.
2. Or should I create the instance of class once in main method and just pass this instance as a parameter to all methods which are called from main method.

The confusion is because I have never seen any example making use of second approach and I think in first approach processing time will be more since instance of class will be created every time we call a method which uses this class.

Comment: Depends entirely on the circumstances. Without code, this question is not answerable.

Comment: If the class consists of data that the other methods need, and doesn't get altered, then you only need to create it once. If, on the other hand, your class is altered by each of the methods, then, well, it depends on what you want to happen.

Comment: And you have a third option. static methods.

Comment: Also you can define your method like static one.

Comment: in any case you using reference of object so doesn't make much difference.

Comment: @dash I really missed that. Thanks guys, Got it.

Comment: The static way possibly lose polymorphic abilities. Else pretty much the same.

Comment: @Harshveer, share the code with the community and we can actually answer this question.

Comment: And a fourth option: make the method an instance method on the object, and just call it on the created instance

Comment: its like ill ask what to use, ref or out... give us a situation or code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the context:

- Sometimtes you need to share the same object between methods because
  the computational cost of creating the instance is high or it is
  simply wrong to have more than one instance of the same object (think
  of fields, file buffers, database connections, etc).
- Sometimes you need to create the object again and again even if has a
  high computational cost because it is the right way of solving the problem (hashing, OCR, searching, de/compressing, etc).
- The most of the time, the cost of creating another instance is negligible and you put modularity and good code first.